# VB.Net - How to get new window URL in GeckoFX60

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

How can i get url from new opened window in GeckoFX60

C# code:

```
void wb1_CreateWindow2(object sender, GeckoCreateWindow2EventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        e.WebBrowser.Navigate(e.Uri);
    }
```

but i can't find e.Uri in vb.net

i tried e.WebBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri but it always null

this is what i tried in vb.net

```
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_CreateWindow(sender As Object, e As Gecko.GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.CreateWindow
    Try
        e.Cancel = True
        Console.WriteLine(e.WebBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GeckoFX 60.x on the CreateWindow event of the GeckoWebBrowser there is no `Uri` property on the `e` GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs object.

To get the URL create a new instance of GeckoBrowser, then you get the URL in Navigating event

[Here's](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/issues/30/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-new-window-in) some sample code from a related thread on the GeckoFX forum:

> ```
> Private Sub Gecko_CreateWindow(sender As Object, e As GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs) Handles Gecko.CreateWindow
>     'Create new form & initialise the browser
>     Dim Frm As New GeckoFrm
>     Dim h = Frm.Gecko.Handle
>
>     'Keep flags for use in Navigating event
>     If e.Flags = GeckoWindowFlags.All Then
>         Frm.Gecko.SetContextFlagsAttribute(ContextFlags.Tab)
>     Else
>         Frm.Gecko.SetContextFlagsAttribute(ContextFlags.Popup)
>     End If
>
>     'Pass back the browser
>     e.WebBrowser = Frm.Gecko
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Gecko_Navigating(sender As Object, e As GeckoNavigatingEventArgs) Handles Gecko.Navigating
>     If Gecko.GetContextFlagsAttribute And ContextFlags.Tab Then
>         'Navigate existing or open tab
>         NavigateTab(e.Uri.ToString)
>     ElseIf Gecko.GetContextFlagsAttribute And ContextFlags.Popup Then
>         If BlockPopup()
>             e.Cancel = True
>             Return
>         Else
>             'navigate existing or open popup
>             NavigatePopup(e.Uri.ToString)
>         End If
>     Else
>         'Not a popup, just show 
>         Show()
>     End If
>     'Clear the popup/tab flags
>     Gecko.SetContextFlagsAttribute(0)
> End Sub
> ```